# Unfolding 3D triangulation surface into planar 2D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, uv-mapping

After a transformation in polar coordination and a triangulation with matplotlib (Triangulation function), I obtain my figure (it's empty inside) in 3D (mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection).I followed this [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800749/delaunay-triangulation-of-points-from-2d-surface-in-3d-with-python). Now, I would like to cut the plot around y-axis and then to unwrap to a 2D plot keeping the colour map. I think it's a problem of a UV mapping, but I would avoid using blender library.
Here an image:
[From this 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPCAy.png) ->
[to 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP23o.png)
Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [here's](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html) a good (if somewhat high-level) reference for how various uv mapping algorithms compare. There's even a library for binding to cgal binaries to python (you'll have to install cgal separately from the bindings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically generating UV coordinates algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578943/automatically-generating-uv-coordinates-algorithms)